# How to add a WaterMark to exsisting pdf document in angular?

Tags: node.js, angularjs, angular, express, watermark

How to add a Watermark in Existing pdf document in angular.
Requirement is watermark has to appear diagonally in pdf Documement

Comment: you should consider doing it on server side. Java or nodeJs has libraries to read or write to pdf files.

Answer (score 1):

It is best to do it in Server-side, as this will not cause any issues in the Client-side. But there are some libraries available. You can use [jsPDF](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF) for adding water mark. If you want the text content to be preserved, it is difficult. You can just convert to image and overlay an opaque version of your watermark. Hope it help!!.. Happy Coding!!

Comment: I have found a way. with pdf-lib package i have achieved it. I did it in client side as i want to attach the watermark that is IP and timestamp when user want to view or download the file.